# malloc kernel panics instead of returning NULL

Tags: memory

I'm attempting to do an exercise from ["Expert C Programming"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131774298) where the point is to see how much memory a program can allocate. It hinges on `malloc` returning `NULL` when it cannot allocate anymore.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int totalMB = 0;
    int oneMeg = 1<<20;
    while (malloc(oneMeg)) {
        ++totalMB;
    }
    printf("Allocated %d Mb total \n", totalMB);
    return 0;
}
```

Rather than printing the total, I get a kernel panic after allocating ~8GB on my 16GB Macbook Pro.

Kernel panic log:

```
Anonymous UUID:       0B87CC9D-2495-4639-EA18-6F1F8696029F

Tue Dec 13 23:09:12 2016

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff800c51f5a4): "zalloc: zone map exhausted while allocating from zone VM map entries, likely due to memory leak in zone VM map entries (6178859600 total bytes, 77235745 elements allocated)"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-3248.50.21/osfmk/kern/zalloc.c:2628
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff91f89bb960 : 0xffffff800c4dab12 
0xffffff91f89bb9e0 : 0xffffff800c51f5a4 
0xffffff91f89bbb10 : 0xffffff800c5614e0 
0xffffff91f89bbb30 : 0xffffff800c5550e2 
0xffffff91f89bbba0 : 0xffffff800c554960 
0xffffff91f89bbd90 : 0xffffff800c55f493 
0xffffff91f89bbea0 : 0xffffff800c4d17cb 
0xffffff91f89bbf10 : 0xffffff800c5b8dca 
0xffffff91f89bbfb0 : 0xffffff800c5ecc86 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: a.out

Mac OS version:
15F34
```

I understand that this can easily be fixed by the doctor's cliche of "It hurts when you do that? Then don't do that" but I want to understand why `malloc` isn't working as expected.

OS X 10.11.5

Comment: Look up "lazy allocation", this is a "feature" of the operating system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the definitive answer to that question, you can look at the source code, which you'll find here:

[zalloc.c source in XNU](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-3789.21.4/osfmk/kern/zalloc.c.auto.html)

In that source file find the function zalloc_internal(). This is the function that gives the kernel panic.

In the function you'll find a "for (;;) {" loop, which basically tries to allocate the memory you're requesting in the specified zone. If there isn't enough space, it immediately tries again. If that fails it does a zone_gc() (garbage collect) to try to reclaim memory. If that also fails, it simply kernel panics - effectively halting the computer.

If you want to understand how zalloc.c works, look up zone-based memory allocators.

Your program is making the kernel run out of space in the zone called "VM map entries", which is a predefined zone allocated at boot. You could probably get the result you are expecting from your program, without a kernel panic, if you allocated more than 1 MB at a time.

In essence it is not really a problem for the kernel to allocate you several gigabytes of memory. However, allocating thousands of smaller allocations summing up to those gigabytes is much harder.

Comment: Changing the amount of memory allocated doesn't cause the program to ever run successfully, but it does make it not kernel panic.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "run successfully". The program is not a real program, but is a teaching example where the malloc function is meant to fail at some point.

Comment: "Run successfully means: allocate as much memory as can be allocated via the while loop. When it tries to allocate the N+1th MB, malloc should return null, exiting the while loop, then it should printf and exit.

Comment: You'll to specify in your question what happens instead of the expected result, if you're not seeing the kernel panic anymore. Also remember that your example is probably a bit outdated - current operating systems will go to great lengths to satisfy your malloc() request including swapping RAM to disk, compressing memory, doing lazy allocations, etc.